# MS graph drives api does not return the updated contents of a file

Tags: file, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

We're using the graph api/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/content?format=pdf from a function app, to generate a pdf version of a given word file stored in a SharePoint library (communication site).

The problem is that if the file is recenty updated, the graph api does not show the updated file. In this case this means that the pdf that is generated is not the same as the file the user can see in word online.

To reproduce the issue:
Open a given file in word online, make a change and wait for the automatic saving.., to complete.
With postman, make a call (application token) to api/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/content for the file and look at the content.

To reproduce you do not need to use the ?format=pdf, the same happens also with the normal /content endpoint.

It sometimes takes more than a minute from the file is saved to the updated content of the file will be returned from the graph endpoint. This is causing us a lot of hassle, so I hope someone has a solution?

Comment: Hi, I have similar issue with excel files that the changes made by user are reflected by Graph API after 1 minute or even more. I haven't found any solution yet.

Comment: It seems to me like a general problem not related Graph API. When access document library on SharePoint in the browser and then edit the file and save changes I see that date time in Modified column on SharePoint is changed with the delay.